# Showing the picture a user just picked?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Our webform has a file upload, and just a regular picture box on it.  Now we already have the code to save the pictures and retrieve them, but how would you display the picture they selected without first saving it, then refreshing the page and displaying it?  Is this a javascript thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "regular picture box" - an `img` element? Does "the picture they selected" mean a picture that the user uploaded?

Comment: Its an image control.  I want it to show the image right after they select it.  Basically show it before it gets uploaded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most browsers do not allow this.  Filed picked will be submitted with the form, but will not be available to javascript.  This is to prevent javascript from having access to local files.

Your best solution is to use AJAX to upload the file, then retrieve it from the server and display it.  This solution makes it so the initial view takes longer, but if the user then decides it is the file they want, you can avoid sending it to the server again and just move it from a temporary storage area to a permanent one.

Answer (score 3):

This definitely is *not* possible with JavaScript. It *might* be possible with a Flash uploader (but I really don't know Flash). JavaScript does not have any sort of direct access to the host's file system.

---

On second thought - it might be possible to inject an `img` tag whose `src` is a `file://` URL. I'm not sure about this, though. Checking now.

Comment: Flash does not allow it either, both can only access a filename and submit the file in a POST request.

Comment: Oh that sucks.  I was hoping this wouldn't be to complicated.

Comment: Yeah, security restrictions can make things harder, but they are definitely there for a reason.

Comment: Matt, it certainly is possible using file protocol.  I've done it before in an intranet application.  Certain permissions must be granted (in IE at least; that's all we had to worry about at the time).  Easiest way is to add the given site to their "Trusted Sites" list.

Comment: @Josh: I definitely can't get it to work in Firefox. Firebug's element tooltip shows the image just fine, but I'm guessing that Firefox's security is set up to prevent this (and I don't feel like digging through the `about:config` page right now)

Comment: @Matt Yeah we never tested it in anything besides IE